# Is it less secure to sign the semantic representation of payload then the lexical representation?

Tags: digital-signature, sha

I think an example illustrates my questions best.
Let's say that I want to send a JSON message.

> { "payload": { "b": 5, "a": 1 }, "signature": "...9oZRsvygw1pTFuRcfXXpFKMRBmkrzdTn6lzS..." }

Alternative X would be to put the payload in a string, possibly base64 encoded, and sign that string.

Alternative Y would be to make a canonical representation of the semantic content of the payload and sign that.
For example I could create and sign the following string instead

> {"a":1,"b":5}

Note that in the semantic representation the keys are ordered based on name and not initial order.

Would it be less or more secure to sign the semantic representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should be secure as far as I can see.

Ordering the keys (assuming the remote reader does not care about ordering in the initial example) in theory makes it slightly more secure because it limits options for the attacker when trying to create a collision - but if you are using a cryptographically secure signature then you shouldn't care either way. You should not think in terms of "more/less secure", only in terms of "secure" and "not secure" where secure is not known to be breakable within a reasonable timeframe with current public knowledge and technology.